# Can I apply $\psi$ to both sides to get $\psi(V)\leqslant\psi(W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U,V,W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces and $\phi:U\to V$
and $\psi:V\to W$ be linear maps.

I want to show that $rank(\psi\circ\phi)\leqslant rank(\psi)$.

I understand that $Im(\phi)\leqslant V$.

Then $\psi(Im(\phi))\leqslant\psi(V)$

$\iff\psi(\phi(U))\leqslant\psi(V)$

$\iff rank(\psi\circ\phi)\leqslant dim(Im(\psi))=rank(\psi)$

Is this possible? If not, when is it not possible?

Comment: $\psi(x)=-x$ is a linear map; does this give you any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. In fact, if $f : X \to Y$ is just a function between two sets $X$ and $Y$, and $A_1,A_2 \subseteq X$, then $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \implies f(A_1) \subseteq f(A_2)$.

Comment: You use the wrong symbol in $Im(\phi)\leq V$, is should be $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)\subseteq V$. The two symbols apply in different situations (there is no $\leq$ between sets, nor $\subseteq$ between numbers), and obey somewhat different rules. You can only say that $x\leq y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$ when $f$ is a monotonically increasing function, but for maps acting element-wise on sets (so $f(X)$ is defined as $\{\,f(x)\mid x\in X\,\}$) it happens that one _always_ has that $X\subseteq Y$ implies $f(X)\subseteq f(Y)$. So in fact your argument can be made to work.